# Update Windows 10 from 1507 to 1607

Tags: windows

I am in a bit of a pickle.

I have a development machine, imaged at **1507** version of windows,
I do need to update it to **1607** Anniversary Update to replicate a bug our software has.

The caveat is version **1703** Creators is already out.

How can I update my system from **1507** to a specific 1607 version of windows 10?
What I've considered

1. **Windows update** - it is not working, I think windows build **1507** is already too old and is excluded from WU.
2. **Windows Update Assistant** - is trying to bump me all the way to **1703** ( Creators Edition ) which is not what I need.
3. **MediaCreationTool** - I have found a media creation tool targeted specifically for **1607** build from a 3rd party website, but I want to upgrade the system, not re-install the whole windows. And my understanding is this tool will re-install not update the image.

What I think would work for me I think is the **Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant** set to update **1607** specifically, but I can't seem to find that option / download. I only found the assistant version that will take you directly to the latest greatest **1703** ( Creators Windows 10 build )

Any help is appreciated,
Maciej

Comment: If you have an MSDN subscription, you could download the 1607 ISOs from Microsoft. It should be possible to mount the 1607 ISO and Update a 1507 system, but I have not tried it. Do you need to specifically upgrade from 1507 to 1607, or do you just need a 1607 version? In the latter case, installing Hyper-V might be better than using your own system.

Comment: As far as I know, all Windows 10 setup media are capable of upgrades as well as fresh installs.  So from a technical standpoint that approach should work, though I don't recommend obtaining Windows media from a third party.  This is exactly the scenario MSDN exists to address.

Comment: (If you have Windows Server 2016, you could use WSUS.)

Comment: Thanks just to give a bit of context I'll obtain the media tomorrow so I'll be able to run from the ISO. The process of getting that ISO is going to be somewhat painful and I probably won't get my hands on the software till the afternoon tomorrow, was hoping I could sort this out via a download available online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OS i'm dealing with is a LTBS ( Long Term Service Branch ). It looks like the only way I can proceed is with the dedicated ISO file, and I'll have to wait to obtain it though the IT department of the company I'm working with ... which will take some time but seems this is the only reasonable way to go.

Other options that I've googled in the opening post won't work in my case. I.e. the update assistant path won't work on this version of Windows 10.

I'm marking this as resolved as I ended up with a resolution to my problem.

In terms of down votes ... appreciate the feedback, initially I got a bit upset but the truth is that I eventually figured this out by googling stuff out, and using SO as a parallel path to speed me up is I guess not the indented use case.

I'll bear that in mind next time.

Thanks,
Maciej

Answer (score 1):

Old builds expire and will not boot. You may have to go to Win 7 pro and try to upgrade to an older build of win 10 from physical media, then don't go online and monitor the PC from a 2nd computer.

Look through your registry hives and try to extract the old build data. You may need forensic software, and I hope you don't have to carve the drive. If it is an SSD, it may be difficult, or not.

Your browser may not even let you download the old builds